# How do I detect if a floating control is closed?

Tags: delphi, controls, docking

In a Delphi program I use ManualFloat to show a TPanel containing a Frame as a floating window for displaying extra information about a selected item. This window is shown/hidden using a checkbox, however if the user closes the floating control using the X on the dock window that Delphi automatically creates, there does not seem to be an event I can hook into to change the state of the checkbox. Does anyone know how this would be accomplished?

Answer (score 5):

You can hook into the `OnClose` event of the floating dock, provided the floating dock has an `OnClose` event. By default it has. It's of type `TCustomDockForm` which is a descendant of `TCustomForm`. But technically it can be a descendant of `TWinControl`. If you, for some reason, change the class of the floating dock to something that wouldn't descend from `TCustomForm`, you may need to tweak this answer.

`OnClose` event of `TCustomDockForm` is not published. Hence you would need to use a *protected hack* to access the event. If you use your own class for the floating dock as in the below sample, you can extend functionality should the need arise.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    ...
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure FloatingDockClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  end;

...

type
  TMyDockForm = class(TCustomDockForm)
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel1.FloatingDockSiteClass := TMyDockForm;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel1.ManualFloat(Rect(200, 200, 420, 280));
//  now we have a floatin dock
  TMyDockForm(Panel1.HostDockSite).OnClose := FloatingDockClose;
end;

procedure TForm1.FloatingDockClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  CheckBox.Checked := False;
end;
```